# Java callback (in another class) to populate private member

Tags: java, callback

Please forgive my Java syntax as I am a Java beginner.

I have 3 classes Main, Tool, ToolResultCallback.

```
class Main {
  private DataList dl;
  public doSomething() {
    Tool t = new Tool();
    ToolResultCallback TRC = new ToolResultCallback();
    t.startSomething(TRC);
  }
}

// in separate file
class Tool {
   public void startSomething(ToolResultCallback TRC) {
   }
}

// in separate file
class ToolResultCallback extends AbstractTRC {
   @Override
   public onEvent(SomeData d) {
      // how to populate DataList of Main?
   }
}
```

How do I populate DataList dl from callback function in another class/ file?

Comment: Pass `dl` to the `ToolResultCallback` constructor, and store it in a field.

Comment: @tgdavies ToolResultCallback is an extended abstract class from a vendor API. Can I just add a custom constructor with a field to it ?

Comment: Yes (if in doubt, try it and see)

Comment: I suggest you post and accept an Answer to your own Question, so this page can be marked as resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass dl to the ToolResultCallback constructor, and store it in a field.

Thanks @tgdavies